# Algorithm for determining most probable geo-location based on multiple bits of information

Tags: algorithm, geolocation

I'm looking for pointers to guide me in the right direction in the construction of an algorithm.

Situation is simple: There are multiple bits of information that may be indicate an individuals' geo location. For instance, recent IP addresses or TLD of email address or information explicitely provided such as town or postal code.

These bits of information may or may not be present, they may have certain levels of accuracy (a postal code would be more accurate than a national TLD) and reliability (IP may be more reliable than a postal code, even if the postal code would be more accurate). Also, information may suffer from aging.

I'm looking to create an algorithm that attempts to determine the most likely location based on this information. I've got several ideas on how to solve this, mostly involving pre-determining and calculating scores for accuracy and reliability, but it's pretty easy to poke holes in this.

Are the any algorithms that handle this particular or similar problems? Perhaps algorithms that deal with data reliability/accuracy in general or actual statistical data on reliability/accuracy of geo-information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the most likely location `L`, given some piece of Information `I`.  That is, you want to maximize the conditional probability

```
P(L|I) -> max
```

Because this function `P(L|I)` is hard to estimate, one typically applies [Bayes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) here:

```
P(L|I) = P(I|L)*P(L) / P(I)
```

The denominator `P(I)` is the probability of that information `I`.  Since this information is fixed, this term is constant and not of interest for finding the maximum above.  `P(L)` is the unconditional probability of a certain location.  Something like the population density at this place might be a good estimate for that.  Finally, you need a model for `P(I|L)`, the probability of getting `I` given location `L`.  For multiple pieces of information this would be the product of the individual probabilities:

```
P(I|L) = P(I1|L)*P(I2|L)*...
```

This works if the individual pieces `I1`, `I2`, ... are [conditionally independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) given the location `L`, which seems to be the case here.  As an example, the likelihood of a certain postal code and the likelihood of some cell tower are generally strongly correlated, but as soon as we assume a specific location `L` the postal code does not influence the likelihood of a cell tower anymore.

Those individual probabilities `P(I1|L) ...` represent the reliability and accuracy of the information and must be provided externally.  You have to come up with some assumptions here.  As a general rule, when in doubt you better be pessimistic about the reliability and accuracy of the information. 
If you are too pessimistic you result will be somewhat off, but if you are too optimistic your result can get totally wrong very quickly.  Another thing you need to keep in mind is the feasibility of the maximization.  A very accurate model for `P(I1|L)` is useless if the effort to find the maximum becomes too high.  Generally picking smooth functions for the models simplifies the optimization in the end.